# Converting a simple recursive haskell function to be tail recursive

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

2 weeks new to haskell and functional programming. In the process of covering foldl and foldr in class, I found that I was quite new to tail recursion and never actually tried writing a tail recursive function before (also new to how foldl traverses a list which is where it came up).

As an exercise, I tried to rewrite the following function to be tail recursive.

```
--replace replaces all instances of value x in a list with y

replace :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace _ _ [] = []
replace x y (h:t) = 
                (if x==h then y: (replace x y t) else h: (replace x y t))

--tail recursive version of the same function
replacet _ _ [] = []
replacet x y (h:t) = 
                    (if x==h then (replacet x y (y:t)) else (replacet x y (h:t)))
```

...But the output is just the following in ghci:

[image: ghci session]

Nothing seems to be running at all, let alone getting an overflow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating that call by hand? What are the arguments to `replacet` in the first recursive call? What are the arguments to `replacet` in the second recursive call?

Comment: And an aside: tail recursion tends not to be particularly relevant in Haskell. Tail call optimization is great for strict languages, where the call stack and the evaluation stack happen to coincide, but in Haskell they tend to be very different. Generally, [guarded recursion](https://www.pls-lab.org/en/Guarded_recursion_(type_theory)) is the thing to aim for instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By my calculation for replacet 1 2 [1,2] 
first call: 1==1 is True, calls replacet 1 2 [2,2]
second call: 1==2 is False, calls replacet 1 2 [2,2]
third call: 1==2 is False, calls replacet 1 2 [2,2]
.
.
and it looks like the third call just goes on and on without hitting the base case. Curious as to why it didn't keep running though (or did it?).
Smart compiler?

Comment: It did keep running, unless you explicitly killed it. If it had finished, you would have gotten another `ghci>` prompt to enter your next expression for evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. Not seeing a way to move through the list without just doing it the "regular"/foldr traversal way above.  Can you explain how foldl would traverse this list if we did it that way?

Comment: If you really want to use tail recursion, even if it will lead to a worse program, note that you need a function with an additional "accumulator" parameter e.g. `f x y t acc`. Here, `t` is a list which will always decrease at each call, like the original program, while the result is slowly accumulated in `acc` (which can increase at each call). Initially then `replacet x y t = f x y t []` will provide the value for `acc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `replacet` never makes any progress. Observe that at each step, your input list stays the same size: you replace `(h:t)` with either `(y:t)` or `(h:t)`, and then call `replacet` on the result.